# How to Create a Run-Time Computed (NotMapped) Value in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a user class in EF Code First that contains a lot of properties, and each user has a collection of "Contacts" which are other users as a subset of the total user population. The other collection "ContactOfOthers" is just the reverse showing who has this user as a contact as this is a many-to-many relationship.

```
public class User {

        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        // Lots of other properties not relevant to this question...

        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsMyContact { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Contacts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> ContactOfOthers { get; set; }

}
```

I introduced a not-mapped (not mapped to DB) property called **IsMyContact**. This is for cases when the user queries for a bunch of users and I need to show in the View which users are already in their contacts list. So this property should be true if the User is part of their "Contacts" collection. It shouldn't be saved to the DB since it can be different for the same user, depending on the user doing the query.

Is there a nice way to do this in a query from the context?  It could of course be brute-forced by doing two queries then iterating through the main one, looking for matches to the user's Contacts collection, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this from one query, projecting a run-time computed column onto this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a way how to populate the `IsMyContact` property in the `User` directly within the query. But an alternative approach could be to introduce a ViewModel which wraps the `User` and has in addition the `IsMyContact` flag:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public bool IsMyContact { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

(The class `User` would not have the `IsMyContact` flag anymore.)

You could then project into this type when you run your query:

```
string me = "That's me"; // name of the user who is selecting

List<UserViewModel> list = context.Users
   .Where(u => ...some filter...)
   .Select(u => new UserViewModel
          {
              IsMyContact = u.ContactOfOthers.Any(c => c.UserName == me),
              User = u
          })
   .ToList();
```

The benefits would be: You need only one round trip and you are not forced to load the whole collection of `Contacts` to determine the `IsMyContactFlag` (but you can if you want to).

The drawback: You need this additional ViewModel type.

Comment: That worked well, thanks for the suggestion.  Only change I made was that the "me" had to in the "ContactOfOthers" collection as I was using that to represent where the user in question was a contact for the particular use.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this but it will be far from a "nice way" because you cannot return instances of your `User` type. You must write custom linq-to-entities query and you must solve two problems:

- You cannot project to mapped types in linq-to-entities
- You cannot access non mapped properties in linq-to-entities

So my high level untested idea about doing this is:

```
var query = from u in ctx.Users
            where u.Id != id // don't include current user - you can add other condition
            join c in ctx.Users
                         .Where(x => x.Id == id) // current user
                         .SelectMany(x => x.Contacts)
                on u.Id equals c.Id into leftJoin
            from y in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
                {
                    UserName = u.UserName,
                    IsMyContact = y != null
                };
```

This should be a query which will load pairs of `UserName` and information if the user is contact or not. If you want `User` instance instead you must do something like this:

```
var users = query.AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(new User
                      {
                          // Project to list in linq-to-objects
                      });
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives good detail on the query requirements and answers the question about accessing the non-mapped type.  Will test that out combined with the notion of a view model suggested by Slauma.